# iOS Safari has a delay in showing elements on click if also focus() on input is called. How delay focus event?

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari

iOS Safari (AFAIK) will not allow setting focus on an input in a `setTimeout` call. Only in a direct click event handler. The problem is this causes a delay in drawing the input (which was previously hidden). How can I make it draw the input and then focus (and pull up the keyboard)?

Example:

```
searchButton.addEventListener( "click", function() {
    myInput.className = "showing"; //This tries to show the input
    myInput.focus(); //This pulls the keyboard but delays drawing the input
});
```

If I put the `focus` event in a `setTimeout` call, it never executes. Are there any options?

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vektgn3j/1/embedded/result/ (click the magnifying glass)

Comment: can you post a demo that shows the delay?

Comment: @ViniciusPinto I posted a jsfiddle that you can view on iOS Safari